# Custom floating decimal points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",final];
```

The above statement displays the float value available in the variable "final" with two digits after decimal point.

I want to display number of decimals in depending upon the number i have give to a integer variable like this

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.if",j,final]
```

Here j is integer variable. Whatever the number i have taken for j that many decimals it should display. I need proper syntax to display the above statement.

Comment: Make it clear. what output you want. what is J value? what is final value? and what you want as a output.

Answer (score 4):

The [IEEE printf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) that [Apple follows](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) states:

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk
>   ( '*' ). In this case an argument of type int supplies the field width
>   or precision.

This means that

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f",j,final]
```

might work, but I have no platform available to test it right now.

Answer (score 2):

`NSNumberFormatter` has the ability to do what you want. Any of the following methods can be set using a variable before you format your string.

```
- (void)setMinimumIntegerDigits:(NSUInteger)number
- (void)setMinimumFractionDigits:(NSUInteger)number
- (void)setMaximumIntegerDigits:(NSUInteger)number
- (void)setMaximumFractionDigits:(NSUInteger)number
```

[Data Formatting Guide - Number Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a one-liner that will do what you want, but you can always do:

```
NSString* formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%%.%if", j];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, final];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *NSNumberFormatter*,

```
 NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[nf setMaximumFractionDigits:j]; // Set the number of decimal places here

label.text = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:final]];

[nf release];
```